# F# adding lists

Tags: recursion, f#, sum, higher-order-functions

How would I go about adding sub-lists.

For example, `[ [10;2;10]; [10;50;10]] ----> [20;52;20]` that is 10+10, 2+50 and 10+10. Not sure how to start this.

Comment: I see that you have changed your question and no longer want the sum of only the second elements, but of the whole sublists.  Can you confirm that the expected result is [20; 52; 20] ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you,

Comment: ok ! I have edited my answer to handle this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Recursive version

We need a helper function to add two lists by summing elements one-to-one.  It is recursive and assumes that both lists are of the same length:

```
let rec sum2Lists (l1:List<int>) (l2:List<int>) = 
    match (l1,l2) with 
    | ([],[]) -> []                    
    | (x1::t1, x2::t2) -> (x1+x2)::sum2Lists t1 t2
```

Then the following recursive function can process a list of lists, using our helper function :

```
let rec sumLists xs = 
    match xs with 
    | [] -> []                                // empty list
    | x1::[] -> x1                            // a single sublist
    | xh::xt -> sum2Lists xh (sumLists xt)    // add the head to recursion on tail
let myres = sumLists mylist
```

#### Solution 2: higher order function

Our helper function can be simplified, using **[`List.map2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map2%5B%27t1,%27t2,%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)**:

```
let sum2hfLists (l1:List<int>) (l2:List<int>) = List.map2 (+) l1 l2
```

We can then use **[`List.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5B%27t,%27state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)** to create an on the flow accumulator using our helper function:

```
let sumhfList (l:List<List<int>>) = 
    match l with 
    | [] -> []                  // empty list of sublist
    | h::[] -> h                // list with a single sublist
    | h::t -> List.fold (fun a x -> sum2hfLists a x) h t
```

The last match case is applied only for lists of at least two sublists.  The trick is to take the first sublist as starting point of the accumulator, and let `fold` execute on the rest of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Fold is a higher order function:

```
let input = [[10;2;10]; [10;50;10]]
input |> Seq.fold (fun acc elem -> acc + (List.nth elem 1)) 0

val it : int = 52
```